# is it alright to have a ref on state (from a reducer) to avoid creating new callbacks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I often have a use case where there is some state in reducer and it needs to be accessed in some callback (useCallback) as well

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
...
const handleAction = useCallback(()=>{
   // dependency on state 
},[])
```

to avoid running useCallbacks on every state change, I reach out for a ref and have the state assigned to it on every render

```
 stateRef.current = state;
```

and then where ever i have to use something from state in a callback, it is accessed from the stateRef. Is this a right way of doing it?

Comment: Sure. What sort of answer are you looking for? There's not much difference between using an `useEffect` with dependency on state and using an `useCallback` with dependency on state is there? You ***are*** talking about using an `useEffect` hook to correctly update the `stateRef` value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply updating the `stateRef` from the component body then this isn't the most correct way as this would be considered an unintentional side-effect. If not using an `useCallback` hook with a dependency on the `state` to re-enclose the current state value in a callback function then an `useEffect` with a dependency on the state value is suggested.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
const stateRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  stateRef.current = state;
}, [state]);

const handleAction = ()=>{
  // access stateRef.current
};
```

This is effectively what `useCallback` accomplishes though, but in a more succinct way.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const handleAction useCallback(() => {
  // access current state value closed over in scope
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, I agree that having the state as dependency for handleAction callback is a correct way of doing it, with multiple callbacks depending on different parts of state, it creates new instances of these functions and further triggers re-renders down the components. How these re-renders can be avoided in a good way can be an interesting find.

Comment: @RahilAhmad Are any of the rerenders problematic or causing any performance issues? React is optimized and runs well out-the-box, target 60fps, or approximately 17ms per render cycle if you are doing some heavy state updates/rerender triggers.